# Error with Maybe and nested resources in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm building my very first Elm SPA, and I'm organizing my components in different folders and modules. Everything worked fine until I changed the main model from this:

```
type alias Model =
{ contacts : Contacts.Model.Model
, contact : Contact.Model.Model
, route : Routing.Route
}
```

To this:

```
type alias Model =
{ contacts : Contacts.Model.Model
, contact : Maybe Contact.Model.Model
, route : Routing.Route
}
```

I've made all the necessary changes in the codebase for this to work, but I'm missing something I can't find because in the main `Update` module I'm constantly getting this compile error:

```
The type annotation for `update` does not match its definition. - The type annotation is saying:

    Msg
    -> { ..., contact : Maybe Contact.Model.Model }
    -> ( { contact : Maybe Contact.Model.Model
    , contacts : Contacts.Model.Model
    , route : Routing.Route
    }
    , Cmd Msg
    )

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    Msg
    -> { ...
    , contact :
          { birth_date : String
          , email : String
          , first_name : String
          , gender : Int
          , headline : String
          , id : Int
          , last_name : String
          , location : String
          , phone_number : String
          , picture : String
          }
    }
    -> ( { contact : Maybe Contact.Model.Model
    , contacts : Contacts.Model.Model
    , route : Routing.Route
    }
    , Cmd Msg
    )
```

It looks like I'm missing to pass the `Maybe Model` somewhere but I can't find it. This is how the update function looks like:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
case msg of
    ContactsMsg subMsg ->
        let
            ( updatedContacts, cmd ) =
                Contacts.Update.update subMsg model.contacts
        in
            ( { model | contacts = updatedContacts, contact = Nothing }, Cmd.map ContactsMsg cmd )

    ContactMsg subMsg ->
        let
            ( updatedContact, cmd ) =
                Contact.Update.update subMsg model.contact
        in
            ( { model | contact = updatedContact }, Cmd.map ContactMsg cmd )
```

Here's the full repo, with the error: https://github.com/bigardone/phoenix-and-elm/tree/feature/routes-refactoring/web/elm

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a type mismatch in `Update.update` function.

```or-tag-here
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
```

You have to process the Maybe value in your `Update.elm`:

```or-tag-here
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ContactsMsg subMsg ->
            let
                ( updatedContacts, cmd ) =
                    Contacts.Update.update subMsg model.contacts
            in
                ( { model | contacts = updatedContacts, contact = Nothing }
                , Cmd.map ContactsMsg cmd
                )

        ContactMsg subMsg ->
            case model.contact of
                Just contact ->
                    let
                        ( updatedContact, cmd ) =
                            Contact.Update.update subMsg contact
                    in
                        ( { model | contact = updatedContact }
                        , Cmd.map ContactMsg cmd
                        )

                Nothing ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Comment: Hi @halfzebra, this did actually work, thank you very much!  The problem that I have now is that it's not mapping correctly with the `Contact.Update.update` function, because when clicking on a contact's gravatar it visits de show route, runs the command to fetch the contact data in the backend but it doesn't enter inside de `FetchContactSucceed` to set the model and display it on screen :(

Comment: @bigardone if you are new to Elm, I would recommend checking out [simpler examples](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples), the one you've got might be a bit overwhelming to grok from the start.